# Can I disable rewrite for specific directory?

Tags: regex, linux, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a website that runs with cakePHP, and i have an aplication in www/application_test that does not work using the rewrite rule.

There is a method to disable the rule for directories within www/application_test?

Follows my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule    ^(app|cake|vendors)/(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        #Include conf/ssl.conf
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad this line just below `RewriteEngine On` line

```
# ignore application_test for any rewrites
RewriteRule ^application_test(/|$) - [NC,L]
```

Comment: doesn't work, its redirect to `hostnameindex.php/?url=application_test/projects` instead of `hostname/application_test/projects`

Comment: There is no rule in your code that is making `?url=...` which could be due to a rule/code you've not posted in your question. Do you have .htaccess in `application_test` also?

Comment: But now is redirecting to cakePHP page not found

Comment: Oh you're welcome. So sorry I was away for few minutes so couldn't attend all the messages.